# How can I read a JsonFile with the following information in Java?I´ve tried with some examples from here but none of them work

Tags: java, json

I´ve been trying to parse this Json format but since it has no name for the array i have no idea how to parse it... Thanks for your help and time.
Im using JSON simple library as a parser.

```
[
    {
       "Name":"John",
       "LastName":"Wick"

     },
    {
       "Name":"Johny",
       "LastName":"Wicked"
    }
]
```

the code im trying to use is this one :

```
   JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray("data/names.json");
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
   String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
   String url = jsonobject.getString("url");
  }
```

Comment: You don't need the array name. Which json parser are you using ?

Comment: Show your code, that you have tried

Comment: Isn't this code work ?? put it in your question

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code there, and explain what problems you're having with it.

Comment: I posted as an answer below, whenever i try to test it it wont work causing a parse exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jackson built in tree model. For example like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootArray = mapper.readTree(new File("c:\\jsonfile.json")); 

for(JsonNode root : rootArray) {    
    // your code
    ... 
}
```